# Audiokit crashes when changing AKPlayer file

Tags: swift, audiokit

I have recently done the migration from AudioKit 3.7 to 4.2 (using Cocoapods), needed for XCode 9.3. I followed the migration guide and changed AKAudioPlayer to AKPlayer.

### The issue

When AKPlayer plays an audio file, AudioKit is crashing with this error:

```
2018-04-17 09:32:43.042658+0200 hearfit[3509:2521326] [avae] AVAEInternal.h:103:_AVAE_CheckNoErr: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:3632:UpdateGraphAfterReconfig: (AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph, kOutputChainFullTraversal, *conn.srcNode, isChainActive)): error -10875
2018-04-17 09:32:43.049372+0200 hearfit[3509:2521326] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10875'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1847d6d8c 0x1839905ec 0x1847d6bf8 0x18a0ff1a0 0x18a11bf58 0x18a12aab0 0x18a128cdc 0x18a1a1738 0x18a1a160c 0x10519192c 0x10519d2f4 0x10519d64c 0x10503afdc 0x10507c4a0 0x10507c01c 0x104f6d9cc 0x1852233d4 0x18477faa8 0x18477f76c 0x18477f010 0x18477cb60 0x18469cda8 0x18667f020 0x18e67d78c 0x10504dfd4 0x18412dfc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Sometimes it happens on the first play, and sometimes the first play is done correctly, but not the second one.

Everything was working great before the migration. I also tried to keep AKAudioPlayer: sounds are played correctly but AKFrequencyTracker does not work anymore.

### Context

This is my setup:

[image: setup]
Quick explanation:

- `AKPlayer 1` plays short audio files (between 1 and 5 seconds)
- `AKFrequencyTracker` is used to display a plot
- `AKPlayer 2` plays background sound (volume must be configurable)
- `AKWhiteNoise` allows to do some manual volume measurements (using `AKMixer 2` volume property)

### Use case example

The user starts an exercise. A sound is played continuously (with looping) using `AKPlayer 2` and the user listens a word (played with `AKPlayer 1`), the plot is displayed. Next, several words are displayed on screen and the user must pick the right one. And a new word is listened... and so on.

So I have to change dynamically the played file of AKPlayer 1. All the code is written in a dedicated class, a singleton. All the nodes are setup in the `init()` function.

```
// singleton
static let main = AudioPlayer()
private init() {

    let silenceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "silence", withExtension: "m4a", subdirectory: "audio")
    self.silenceFile = silenceUrl!

    self.mainPlayer = AKPlayer(url: self.silenceFile)!
    self.mainPlayer.volume = 1.0

    self.freqTracker = AKFrequencyTracker(self.mainPlayer, hopSize: 256, peakCount: 10)

    let noiseUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cocktail-party", withExtension: "m4a", subdirectory: "audio")
    self.noiseFile = noiseUrl!

    self.noisePlayer = AKPlayer(url: self.noiseFile)!

    self.noisePlayer.volume = 1.0
    self.noisePlayer.isLooping = true

    let mixer = AKMixer(self.freqTracker, self.noisePlayer)

    self.whiteNoise = AKWhiteNoise(amplitude: 1.0)
    self.whiteNoiseMixer = AKMixer(self.whiteNoise)
    self.whiteNoiseMixer.volume = 0
    self.mixer = AKMixer(mixer, self.whiteNoiseMixer)

    AudioKit.output = self.mixer
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }

    // stop directly the white noise mixer
    self.whiteNoise.stop()
    self.whiteNoiseMixer.volume = self.whiteNoiseVolume

    self.mainPlayer.completionHandler = {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let timer = self.timer {
                timer.invalidate()
                self.timer = nil
            }

            if let completion = self.completionHandler {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { (_) in
                    completion()
                    self.completionHandler = nil
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To change the `AKPlayer 1` audio file, I use this function, on the same class:

```
func play(fileUrl: URL, tracker: @escaping TrackerCallback, completion: (() -> Void)?) throws {

    self.completionHandler = completion
    let file = try AKAudioFile(forReading: fileUrl)

    self.mainPlayer.load(audioFile: file)
    self.mainPlayer.preroll()

    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.trackerRefreshRate, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        tracker(self.freqTracker.frequency, self.freqTracker.amplitude)
    }

    self.mainPlayer.play()
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are replacing into the player, but if the format of the file is different from what you had before, channels, samplerate, etc -- you should create a new AKPlayer instance rather than load into the same one. If your files are all the same format then it should work ok.

That said, I haven't seen the crash you show.

Another thing that is dangerous in your code is force unwrapping those optionals - you should guard against things being nil. AKPlayer actually uses AVAudioFile, no need for AKAudioFile.

```
guard let akfile = try? AVAudioFile(forReading: url) else { return }

if akfile.channelCount != player?.audioFile?.processingFormat.channelCount ||
    akfile.sampleRate != player?.audioFile?.processingFormat.sampleRate {

    AKLog("Need to create new player as formats have changed.")
}
```